# why Server.Transfer changes the font in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to show an alert message that "You have been redirected to Logout page" then redirect to logout page.I followed below snippet.While redirecting the font style changes, which is not required. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Regards,
Sathya S

```
Response.Write("<SCRIPT> alert('You have been redirected to Logout page!');</SCRIPT>");
Server.Transfer("Logout.aspx");
```

before server.transfer

[image]

after server.transfer

[image]

Comment: What font style changes ?

Comment: On the web, you're dealing with request/response. The browser has sent a request, and is now waiting for a response. You don't have an option to send *two* responses. Why do you feel a need to tell someone that they're heading to the logout page - will they not notice when they land there?

Comment: What event are you doing this response.write on? Ajax? Button click? What does the html response look like (ie does something include some css around the script that you are pushing to the client in this bad way?)

Comment: Without inspecting this HTML this is difficult to tell. I would guess that the first page has some styling that the second page does not. It could be the other way around. Try using FireBug(FireFox) or Chrome developer tools to identity what the difference is. Once you've discovered the difference you'll be able to track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is changing the font is the `Response.Write` and not the `Server.Transfer`.

Use this: ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock...[check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)